# Where i can find padlock image C# visual studio, or net

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

Where I can find that image? I want locked and unlocked. Are these default images implemented in visual studio?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this because this is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Visual Studio Image Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825)

Comment: I didn't find the image.

Answer (score 0):

Currently It will be a good choice to use PictureBox and upload images to achieve this purpose. Here are the steps:

1. Add PictureBox control.
2. Click the arrow in the upper right corner of the PictureBox.
3. You can click ‘Choose Image’ and select local resource to import the icon you need.
4. At last, you can change the size mode of the PictureBox to an appropriate size.

[image]

You can find the lock-icon and lock-open-icon online. If you don’t mind, please use these I found.

[image]
[image]